# How do i traverse this json data in java?

Tags: java, android, json

Hi i want to traverse this json data using android fast networking library but i am not able to do so. Can someone please suggest a way to be able to fetch id and filename of all the objects in the array?

Note -It has to be done using ANDROID FAST NETWORKING LIBRARY -https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

```
 [
          {
            "_id": "598ae8773376673353ef6da6",
            "filename": "nldcjjzpesyhkkx1502275703450.jpg",
            "votes": 33,
            "__v": 0
          },
          {
            "_id": "598ae83b3376673353ef6da5",
            "filename": "xlwkfcxicwhqibw1502275643486.jpg",
            "votes": 31,
            "__v": 0
          },
          {
            "_id": "598a2e7000c6717c3c04e534",
            "filename": "ndkiqptbifqmnjz1502228078447.jpg",
            "votes": 19,
            "__v": 0
          },
          {
            "_id": "5989ece9673738c027377710",
            "filename": "seicmgkzubzavfy1502211303478.jpg",
            "votes": 13,
            "__v": 0
          }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) lib or you can retrieve using for loop like this:

```
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(yourResponseStrOrJson);
    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.d("ID", jsonObject.getString("_id"));
        //TOTO retrive other element
    }
}catch (JSONException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: No i need to use the android fast networking library - Here is the link 
 https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking

Comment: @Knightcube, put above code in onResponse method and do you tast

Comment: Yeah it is working now. Actually i had some other connection issues that is why it was not working. My Bad

Comment: glad work code worked